# AngularJS: How can I initialize controller embedded with ajax loaded template?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am loading an angular 'template' using ajax. This template renders a bootstrap modal form when I call $compile ... this works, everything fine here. But what I need is support of embedding controllers within this lazy loaded 'template' (Preferably I want to handle this client side so on server side everything can just look normal).

The thing is when I use ng-controller inside this template and define a function controller inside a **script** tag it fails. It tells me it cant find the controller function. I understand why this is happening, the script has not yet been initialized. I am just looking for a solution. How can I make the embedded **script** tags initialize first? Should I extract them, inject them somewhere and then compile the remainder? Or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

Lets have look in AngularJS documentation and show the [integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop).
So you can see that AngularJS have its own event loop, which consists of three phases: **compile**, **digest** and **apply**.

When you call `compile` it will only loads the html markup and insert it. You should call `apply` also.
With `apply` you will set the execution scope. This will register an watcher that listens to changes.